Humidity in shed: options for shelf panels
I have a brick shed outside, with barely any ventilation except for 16 1x5cm slots between bricks. The floor is bare concrete.
I renovated last year, and among other things painted the floor and installed some of these storage shelves with thin MDF panels. Turns out I'm stupid and left inside a bucket with water while we were gone for the Christmas holidays (20 days). This is the Netherlands, with slightly below 0ºC and very high humidity. When we came back, the MDF shelves had mold all over the place (see pictures), cardboard boxes were shaggy, the plywood ceiling turned black just above the bucket, and the water in it was of course frozen.
My question is twofold:

I don't know if I was just unlucky and it was all caused by the bucket with water, or if I made a mistake painting the floor. Before, the concrete would absorb the little water left by the bikes, for example, but now it takes longer because of the paint. Ideas? Should I remove the paint? Improve ventilation? It seems that in the winter the relative humidity gets over 90% at night, but so does the neighbor's, whose floor is not painted.

Regardless of the question above, I need to replace the panels for the shelves. I was looking for something cheap, but mainly for something that will not grow mold again. I was thinking about OSB3 with painted edges. Would that be enough? Any other options?


Thanks a lot!



The bucket of water did not help.  More ventilation will help.  Usually for passive ventilation you want intake air near the bottom and exhaust near the top.  You want to ask a brick worker, but should be able to remove the odd brick near the bottom/drill a few vent holes(5 to 10cm), and have an exit vent near the top of the roof.  MDF and moisture does not mix well.  Unless well sealed, replacement might be needed.

For high humidly, you probably  want pressure treated/exterior wood/plywood.  OSB3 might be a good second choice.

You're definitely going to need more ventilation, and likely a fan.  Safety permitting, you may also be able to install heating rods to reduce the humidity.

@crip659 thanks, never thought about bottom/top for ventilation. What are your thoughts about the floor paint? Good idea to remove it and go back to the concrete floor?

@EndAntisemiticHate yeah, was thinking about a small solar-powered fan

I think that's an excellent idea and will likely help.  Take a look at low power heating rods too.  They can typically be powered by solar as well.
